# How to change HTML5 date format using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, date-format

I am using HTML5 element type="date" for the date this display in the browser as DD-MM-YYYY format but I want to change the format to this 'Jul 5, 2018' using jQuery.

How can I do this? Any plugin? Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control">
```

Comment: refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Thanks for this link

Answer (score -1):

**If you want you need to use date.js to work**

```
var getDate = new Date('2018-01-06');
var dateGet = getDate.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Otherwise you can do this

If you have date format lik 2018-05-26

```
var dateGet = '2018-05-26'.split('-');
var finalDate = dateGet[1] + '-' + dateGet[2] + '-' + dateGet[0].slice(-2);
```

Now do the console.log or alert to check
`console.log(finalDate)` or `alert(finalDate)`